# Laravel 5.1 Does not recognize the timestamp field in postgres

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel-5

I'm working with Laravel 5.1. But I cannot query the database:

I just do:  User::all(); on my UserController

Here is the error:

```
1/1
InvalidArgumentException in Carbon.php line 414:
Trailing data
in Carbon.php line 414
at Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2015-07-19 20:32:47.313') in Model.php line 2858
at Model->asDateTime('2015-07-19 20:32:47.313') in Model.php line 2384
at Model->attributesToArray() in Model.php line 2361
at Model->toArray() in Collection.php line 871
at Collection->Illuminate\Support\{closure}(object(User))
at array_map(object(Closure), array(object(User), object(User), object(User))) in Collection.php line 873
at Collection->toArray() in Collection.php line 894
at Collection->toJson() in Response.php line 66
at Response->morphToJson(object(Collection)) in Response.php line 44
at Response->setContent(object(Collection)) in Response.php line 202
at Response->__construct(object(Collection)) in Router.php line 1225
at Router->prepareResponse(object(Request), object(Collection)) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 113
at ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 139
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 114
at ControllerDispatcher->callWithinStack(object(UserController), object(Route), object(Request), 'index') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 69
at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(Request), 'App\Http\Controllers\UserController', 'index') in Route.php line 201
at Route->runWithCustomDispatcher(object(Request)) in Route.php line 134
at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line 704
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 139
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 706
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 671
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 631
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 229
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 139
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 50
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(VerifyCsrfToken), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 54
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(ShareErrorsFromSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 62
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(StartSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(AddQueuedCookiesToResponse), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(EncryptCookies), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 42
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 118
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 86
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
```

This is my user model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    //
}
```

This is my UserController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $users = User::all();
        // return view('users.index', compact('users'));
        return $users;
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  Request  $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

And This is my postgres SQL code

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users CASCADE;

CREATE TABLE users
(
   id              serial         NOT NULL,
   code            varchar(255),
   login           varchar(50)     NOT NULL,
   name            varchar(255)    NOT NULL,
   email           varchar(255)    NOT NULL,
   password        varchar(60)     NOT NULL,
   remember_token  varchar(100),
   created_at      timestamp       NOT NULL,
   updated_at      timestamp       NOT NULL
);

-- Column id is associated with sequence public.users_id_seq

ALTER TABLE users
   ADD CONSTRAINT users_pkey
   PRIMARY KEY (id);

COMMIT;
```

What's wrong?? Please help.
Is there any configuration file that I missing??

Comment: read about resolution here: http://laravel.io/forum/08-31-2014-invalidargumentexception-for-postgresql-database

Comment: `at Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2015-07-19 20:32:47.313')` note that format does not match value, it includes milliseconds appart from seconds. Could you post your migration file to create the users table? Or did you just run your own SQL?

Comment: I don't use migrations, just raw SQL. Are there any advantages using migrations??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After reading this http://laravel.io/forum/08-31-2014-invalidargumentexception-for-postgresql-database I decided to create model that extends default model class and replaces getDateFormat with custom code.
Because changing classes in vendor directory is bad idea.
I hope it helps:

```
class FixedModel extends Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model {
    public function getDateFormat()
    {
        return 'Y-m-d H:i:s.u';
    }
}

class User extends FixedModel {}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks I'll try that. But is this a bug right?? It should be fixed in the default version of laravel.

Comment: I think it's not, because I have downloaded the last version of laravel and updated it with the composer

Comment: I have to say it's not a bug. Every database has it's own realizations of timestamp. So it's about version of PG.

Answer (score 2):

You should declare `$dateFormat` in your model class:

```
protected $dateFormat = 'Y-m-d H:i:s.u';
```